# How to intract with an element when there are two same attribute values in selenium i am using Hydrib Framework

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, attributes, web-inspector

Here is HTML code so how to inspect elements when there is same attribute value

[image]

Comment: i dont know about the Hydrib Framework but you can use *xpath* for html tags who have same attributes.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases use surrounding elements to make them unique. You can pic the parent which is not same.

For first element, Use below xpath:

```
//div[@class='goog-control result 1h-vars 1h-root goog-control-hover']//div[@class='1h-metric__value']
```

And this is for second one :

```
//div[@class='goog-control result 1h-vars 1h-root]//div[@class='1h-metric__value']
```

**Note**: please make sure spelling are correct. I have written by seeing in the image.

Comment: Hi Narendra,

Thanks for you support.
Your answer is absolutely right but as you said that 
1st element:- 
//div[@class='goog-control result 1h-vars 1h-root goog-control-hover']
2nd element:-
//div[@class='goog-control result 1h-vars 1h-root] difference is this "goog-control-hover" but while running it automatically changes class name.
By clicking on 2nd button 1st element to 2nd element goog-control-hover moves and again if we click on 1st button 2nd element to 1st element it changes goog-control-hover.


Kindly help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

So, here just an attribute is appended on the focused element.

In that case, u can look up for the child unique attribute.
Here, it seems, u can fetch the label and get it filtered with the text and get the desired webelement.

Either way, look up for the attribute:-

```
List<WebElement> redundantElement = driver.findElements("By Locator");
:css-selector :- "div.goog-control-hover"

for(Webelement checkbox : redundantElement){
    if(checkbox.getAttribute("class").contains("goog-control-hover")
        {
         // Do Specific action on the element u want to, "Hovered Element", else put negation on if checkpoint for alternat case
        }
}
```

else use nth-child(), to get the element but that would be somewhat static.